# Retrieving JSON from a Web API on Android

Tags: java, c#, android, json, asp.net-web-api

Here... I have a Web API with a MessageController that will respond to my request from Android and send JSON (Hello World - Just to test it out).

```
public class MessageController : ApiController
    {
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendAsync()
        {

            return Ok(new { text = "hello world" });
        }
    }
```

From my Android App I want to request JSON from my API. I have requested from other Web APIs like  currency etc. And it worked, but same method don't work on my API.

Here it is:

```
public void requestMessagesFromApi(View v)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        final String response = getJSON(finalUrl);
        TextView msgTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);
        msgTV.setText(response);
    }



public String getJSON(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get ResonseCode -1. Don't know why. In Final URL I am targeting my Web API on Azure:

```
 finalUrl ="http://<hereIsMineWebApiURL>/api/message"
```

I'm sure that I'm wrong in API.

Comment: why do you have `("Content-length", "0")`

Comment: I removed it, still get exception on  int status = c.getResponseCode();, throws me on final.

Comment: did you check your api server ? e.g. through normal browser?

Comment: When i go to mine Api it opens mine Index. But when i target api/message, i get: 

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
</Error>

I'm sure that i make error on Api side. Don't know where

Comment: well, at least we know, its not the App, just review the server, try to narrow down the problem, if you couldn't find the problem, post a new question in SO

Comment: I used that API for registration, and I have authorization handler registered  WebApiConfig. 
Maybe I need to authorize or something like that. I don't know what first go.